# use typescript value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

hi i need to create a simple calcuator in angular with javascript .

now i use this code in javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  switch (this.operator) {
    case '+':
      this.ResultAns += this.first + this.second;
      break;
    case '-':
      this.ResultAns += this.first - this.second;
      break;
    case '*':
      this.ResultAns += this.first * this.second;
      break;
    case '/':
      this.ResultAns += this.first / this.second;
      break;
  }
```

and i defined this variable n type script:

```
  first: string = "";
  second: string = "";
  operator: string = "";
  ResultAns: number;
```

now when i need to use this variable it show `undefined` .

how can i use this variable in javascript ???????

Comment: May I ask why you use JQuery's document ready in Angular app?

Comment: I don't see any Angular code there, your code seems very far from a [mcve]. I'd recommend you to reproduce the issue on a StackBlitz - there is an Angular Boilerplate waiting for you [right there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-boilerplate)! Simply edit the StackBlitz so as to reproduce the issue, then link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in JavaScript has different scopes. You could read a blog post, [I googled one for you](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8).
When you use a `function` keyword, `this` will refer to the caller (in your case, to `document`).

You can use an **arrow function** :

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  switch (this.operator) {
    case '+':
      this.ResultAns += this.first + this.second;
      break;
    case '-':
      this.ResultAns += this.first - this.second;
      break;
    case '*':
      this.ResultAns += this.first * this.second;
      break;
    case '/':
      this.ResultAns += this.first / this.second;
      break;
  }
```

Anyway, in Angular, you shouldn't manipulate real DOM in your components. Hence, the use of `jQuery` is highly debatable, in most cases you should avoid it.

Comment: hey man . thank you . please guid me for this problm , how can convert string to number in javascript ?? i use this but it not worked `parseInt(this.first) + parseInt(this.second)`

Comment: @fizikShimi You add a `+` : in your case `+this.first + +this.second`.